# How to Remove specific graph objects in Zedgraph

Tags: c#, object, zedgraph

I'm trying to remove a specific graph object from the zedgraph, is it possible....?

I have a zedgraph, which has multiple curves and multiple graph objects...

```
GraphPane pane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;

// Create two Line Onjects
LineObj BlueLine = new LineObj(Color.Blue, 10, 10, 10, 100);
LineObj RedLine = new LineObj(Color.Red, 90, 10, 90, 100);

// Add the line objects
pane.GraphObjList.Add(BlueLine);
pane.GraphObjList.Add(RedLine);
```

I know that with the help of

```
pane.GraphObjList.Clear();
```

I can clear all the objects but I want to remove the Redline alone..?

Thanks for your time...:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `LineItem` instead of `LineObj`, you can use `LineItem1.clear()` to remove single curves.

You can fill it with a `PointPairList`, and add it to your pane:

`LineItem1 = pane.AddCurve("CurveName", PointPairList1, Color.White, SymbolType.None)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, it should solve my problem...:)